# How to detect a browser's layout engine in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser, detection, layout-engine

I want to create different behaviors according to the [layout engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_layout_engines#Graphical) of the client's browser. How to detect if it's WebKit (Chrome, Safari, Yandex, Midori), Gecko (Firefox, K-Meleon, Netscape), Trident (IE), or others?

Comment: @LeshaOgonkov Different layout engines behave differently in some situations (e.g.: [google map's InfoBubble](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html/) is only animated in WebKit).

Comment: What you want to do when aimed engine become act differently from your expectations?

Comment: @LeshaOgonkov ouch... that's a personal question ;P But I could use an entirely different pop-up instead.

Comment: I think you on a wrong way with engine detection, better use feature detection

Comment: @LeshaOgonkov by feature detection, do you mean identifying why a certain plugin's feature behaves differently in different layout engines? How would that avoid querying for the layout engine? And wouldn't you take much more time detecting a certain feature in an unfamiliar plugin (which in the end may not work in other engines)?

Comment: By feature detection i mean detection of certain features you actually need to implement your task (animation support, for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into `navigator.userAgent` (just type it in your browser's console). You can search as follows (case insensitive):

```
if(navigator.userAgent.search(/trident/i)>0){
    //Internet Explorer
} else if(navigator.userAgent.search(/webkit/i)>0){
    //Chrome, Safari
} else if(navigator.userAgent.search(/???/i)>0){ //replace ??? by the appropriate engine
    //others
} else if(navigator.userAgent.search(/gecko/i)>0){
    //Firefox
}
```

Leave **Gecko** for the last condition since the *userAgent* property may contain the expression "like Gecko", WebKit browsers do and IE as well:

> IE's **navigator.userAgent**: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; InfoPath.3; rv:11.0) **like Gecko**"

The `navigator.appVersion` property may contain the same information as `navigator.userAgent` but in some browsers it doesn't:

> Firefox's **navigator.appVersion**: "5.0 (Windows)"