# How to correctly check the browser engine and apply the needed code?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

Something like this:

If (Gecko) do caseOne
else do caseTwo

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32617798/how-to-detect-a-browsers-layout-engine-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use user agent as follows

```js
{
  var browser = "";
  if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Gecko") != -1) browser = "Gecko";
  

  if (browser == "Gecko") {
  
  console.log('browser: ' + browser);
  
  
  } else {
  
  console.log('browser: ' + browser);
  
  }

}
```

Comment: navigator.userAgent
"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36"

Comment: This text from navigator.userAgent in Chrome